# Ignore migration by Django verison

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-migrations, django-1.8

I am migrating a project from Django 1.7 to 1.8 and I need to run an extra migration script to support a user model.

By the way, I need to save the compatibility with the 1.7 version which this migration makes it wrong.

As the migration scripts are auto-generated is there still any way to add some conditions to avoid running some specific migrations by version of Django?

Comment: Migrations are just Python files, you can edit them and add any logic you need.

Comment: yes I know this, the problem is if I ignore class declaration it will face error, if  I define it with no attribute, syncdb will fail.

Comment: It would help if you show e.g. 1/ the current migration file, 2/ what you want to change, 3/ model changes (if not covered by 2). Because I don't think you can combine  compatibility with 1.7 *and* the need a migration for a changed user model (did the user model change between 1.7 and 1.8?).

Comment: lets not  miss the point , problem is to have a conditional migration.